# Multiple 'GET' forms in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following HTMLHelper extension to create a submit button that would work with JavaSceript turned off:

```
public static string ActionButton(this HtmlHelper helper, string value,
                        string action, string controller, object routeValues = null, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var a = (new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext))
                            .Action(action, controller, routeValues);

    var form = new TagBuilder("form");
    form.Attributes.Add("method", "get");
    form.Attributes.Add("action", a);
    form.Attributes.Add("style", "display:inline");

    var input = new TagBuilder("input");
    input.Attributes.Add("type", "submit");
    input.Attributes.Add("value", value);
    input.Attributes.Add("class", "button");
    input.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

    form.InnerHtml = input.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);

    return form.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
}
```

The problem is, that it works fine if there is only one of these buttons on a page but if there is more than 1, weird things start happening.  For example, if I have the following declaration in a loop:

```
<td class="tac"><%=Html.ActionButton("Choose", "CreateNewAuditFromExisting", "Audit", new { auditUid = audit.Uid })%></td>
```

The following HTML gets generated and which looks good to me:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tac">
       <form action="/admin/Audit.mvc.aspx/CreateNewAuditFromExisting?auditUid=906e26e5-6505-4a70-b19a-9e8a00d74a88" method="get"style="display:inline">  
          <input class="button" type="submit" value="Choose">
       </form>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="tac">
      <form action="/admin/Audit.mvc.aspx/CreateNewAuditFromExisting?auditUid=899eb11d-54a8-448f-9539-9e8a00d7c652" method="get" style="display:inline">
         <input class="button" type="submit" value="Choose">
       </form>
     </td>
</tr>
```

When there is more than 1 form, the querystring gets ignored when submitting the form.  I have other weird behaviour when more than one of these buttons is on a form.

My question is, is this behaviour to be expected for multiple 'get' forms?

Also, is there a better way to create a button that will work when JavaScript is disabled and will navigate like I am trying to achieve?

Comment: My guess is that you want the button, because of it's style... In that case you might want to make it a normal link, and style it like a button.

Comment: @R0MANARMY: There is a button in the first form also. For some reason it's on the same line as the form tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the GET method in the form, the querystring will be the data from the fields within the form. That will replace the querystring that you have put in the URL, and that should happen regardless if there is a single form or multiple forms in the page.

Put the value in a hidden field in the form instead of in the URL. Example:

```
<form action="/admin/Audit.mvc.aspx/CreateNewAuditFromExisting" method="get" style="display:inline">
  <input type="hidden" name="auditUid" value="899eb11d-54a8-448f-9539-9e8a00d7c652">
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Choose">
</form>
```

Another way to get the same result would be to simply use a link:

```
<a href="/admin/Audit.mvc.aspx/CreateNewAuditFromExisting?auditUid=906e26e5-6505-4a70-b19a-9e8a00d74a88">Choose</a>
```

Comment: A link is no problem. Getting a button to behave like a link when javascript is turned off, is the problem.

Comment: @dagda1: You seem to have missed the point of the answer. I added an example above to show what I mean.

Comment: @dagda1: Why are you forcing a button to act like a link when there's a perfectly good element designed to **be** a link?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility - you could put all the submit buttons inside a single form and give your submit button a name like the following:

```
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit_899eb11d-54a8-448f-9539-9e8a00d7c652" value="Choose" />
```

Only the submit button that a user presses is submitted with the form post, so all you need to do serverside is loop through the querystring parameters and dig out the one prefixed with `submit_` to find out which one was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button name="buttonAction" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value=1>@Buttons.AddEntry</button>
<button name="buttonAction" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value=2>@Messages.FillExistingEntry</button>
```

then the post method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult yourActionName(string buttonAction, yourViewModel model)
```

the buttonAction param contains value of the button, so now you can pick the one you want and do:

```
return View("../YourController/YourAction", model);
```